# SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "Tile_-4412407809"

Tags: swift

I'm trying to find out what is causing this Tile_xxxxx name to be some sort of long random number in this code.

```
SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "Tile_-4412407809"
```

The code related to it is in this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/54-how-to-make-a-game-like-candy-crush-with-spritekit-and-swift-part-2

**The Tile name is set in the swift file GameScene.swift line 144.**

```
let name = String(format: "Tile_%ld", value)
```

and it's probably best if I put the code from the file in here. Something is setting "value" to something it can't use. But what? Where is it getting hashValue from

```
var value = topLeft.hashValue



import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
  // Sound FX
  let swapSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Chomp.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
  let invalidSwapSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Error.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
  let matchSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Ka-Ching.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
  let fallingCookieSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Scrape.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
  let addCookieSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Drip.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
  var level: Level!
  let tilesLayer = SKNode()
  let cropLayer = SKCropNode()
  let maskLayer = SKNode()

  let tileWidth: CGFloat = 32.0
  let tileHeight: CGFloat = 36.0

  let gameLayer = SKNode()
  let cookiesLayer = SKNode()
  var swipeHandler: ((Swap) -> Void)?

  private var swipeFromColumn: Int?
  private var swipeFromRow: Int?
  private var selectionSprite = SKSpriteNode()

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder) is not used in this app")
  }

  override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)

    anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

    // This is the Witches background image
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
    background.size = size
    addChild(background)
    addChild(gameLayer)
    gameLayer.isHidden = true

    let layerPosition = CGPoint(
      x: -tileWidth * CGFloat(numColumns) / 2,
      y: -tileHeight * CGFloat(numRows) / 2)
    tilesLayer.position = layerPosition
    maskLayer.position = layerPosition
    cropLayer.maskNode = maskLayer
    gameLayer.addChild(tilesLayer)
    gameLayer.addChild(cropLayer)

    cookiesLayer.position = layerPosition
    cropLayer.addChild(cookiesLayer)
    let _ = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "GillSans-BoldItalic")
  }

  func addSprites(for cookies: Set<Cookie>) {
    for cookie in cookies {
      let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: cookie.cookieType.spriteName)
      sprite.size = CGSize(width: tileWidth, height: tileHeight)
      sprite.position = pointFor(column: cookie.column, row: cookie.row)
      cookiesLayer.addChild(sprite)
      cookie.sprite = sprite

      // Give each cookie sprite a small, random delay. Then fade them in.
      sprite.alpha = 0
      sprite.xScale = 0.5
      sprite.yScale = 0.5

      sprite.run(
        SKAction.sequence([
          SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.25, withRange: 0.5),
          SKAction.group([
            SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 0.25),
            SKAction.scale(to: 1.0, duration: 0.25)
            ])
          ]))
    }
  }

  func addTiles() {
    for row in 0..<numRows {
      for column in 0..<numColumns {
        if level.tileAt(column: column, row: row) != nil {
          let tileNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "MaskTile")
          tileNode.size = CGSize(width: tileWidth, height: tileHeight)
          tileNode.position = pointFor(column: column, row: row)
          maskLayer.addChild(tileNode)
        }
      }
    }

    for row in 0...numRows {
      for column in 0...numColumns {
        let topLeft     = (column > 0) && (row < numRows)
          && level.tileAt(column: column - 1, row: row) != nil
        let bottomLeft  = (column > 0) && (row > 0)
          && level.tileAt(column: column - 1, row: row - 1) != nil
        let topRight    = (column < numColumns) && (row < numRows)
          && level.tileAt(column: column, row: row) != nil
        let bottomRight = (column < numColumns) && (row > 0)
          && level.tileAt(column: column, row: row - 1) != nil

        var value = topLeft.hashValue
        value = value | topRight.hashValue << 1
        value = value | bottomLeft.hashValue << 2
        value = value | bottomRight.hashValue << 3


        // Values 0 (no tiles), 6 and 9 (two opposite tiles) are not drawn.
        if value != 0 && value != 6 && value != 9 {
          let name = String(format: "Tile_%ld", value)

          //print(name)

          let tileNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: name)
          tileNode.size = CGSize(width: tileWidth, height: tileHeight)
          var point = pointFor(column: column, row: row)
          point.x -= tileWidth / 2
          point.y -= tileHeight / 2
          tileNode.position = point
          tilesLayer.addChild(tileNode)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed.

Change

```
var value = topLeft.hashable
value = value | topRight.hashable << 1
value = value | bottomLeft.hashable << 2
value = value | bottomRight.hashable << 3

to

var value = (topLeft ? 1 : 0)
value = value | (topRight ? 1 : 0) << 1
value = value | (bottomLeft ? 1 : 0) << 2
value = value | (bottomRight ? 1 : 0) << 3
```